# OpenCV, C++ cvCaptureFromFile not working but Python VideoCapture is

Tags: c++, python, opencv

Im working with some legacy code that I need to use, as well as do some work in Python.  I am able to read from file in Python but not in C++.  Here is the C++ code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  CvCapture *capture = NULL; 

  capture = cvCaptureFromFile("path/to/foo.mov");
  if (!capture) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot open " << "path/to/foo.mov" <<   std::endl; 
    return 1; 
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Not working as in capture == False.  I was able to get this working by completely reinstalling OpenCV.  I hate when that is the solution, but what can you do?